# react-scripts is not recognize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I have problem about react project when I hit enter the command like yarn start so I have face the mentioned problem like react-script is not recognize internal or external command. I have this script in dependencies but still I face this problem.
I have the latest version of node, and I have updated npm but still I have this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: npm add react-scripts --include=dev

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are inside the project folder before you use the `yarn start` command.
2. Or try deleting the cache and node-modules and package-lock.json and re-install it.
3. You can try manually installing `react-scripts` for your application.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Try `yarn install`

2 . If the problem is not solved `yarn add react-scripts --dev`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove node_module folder
2. Remove yarn.lock file
3. On cmd, run npm cache clean --force
4. yarn add react-scripts